# Does Go cross-compile on Ubuntu to a Windows executable?

Tags: go, cross-compiling

Using Ubuntu, what steps should I take to compile Go source code into a Windows executable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Building Windows Go programs on Linux](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling)